# Lowest regular season win-loss percentage to qualify for the NBA Playoffs?

Tags: trivia, basketball, nba

Taking a look at the last 3 years, the Atlanta Hawks (2014) and Memphis Grizzlies (2015) have had the lowest W/L percentage of all the teams that qualified for the playoffs in their respective years, both teams qualifying for the 8th seed in their conferences with a W/L percentage of 41.5% (34W-48L).

My question is, what is the lowest win-loss percentage record for a team that has qualified for a playoff spot in NBA history? (Not including the lockout shortened seasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.sbnation.com/nba/2014/4/4/5581984/nba-playoffs-history-bulls-spurs-knicks-cavaliers), the lowest win-loss percentage records for a team that has qualified for a playoff spot in NBA history are:

1. [1967-1968 Chicago Bulls](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1968.html) - .354 win-loss percentage (29-53 win-loss record)
2. [1985-1986 Chicago Bulls](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1986.html) - .366 (30-52)
3. [1987-1988 San Antonio Spurs](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1988.html) - .378 (31-51)